# falang and menu alias translation

Tags: php, joomla

I installed falang for an English-Spanish site. Everything was working fine until I started  the menus items translation. The thing is that falang doesn't translate the menu alias. Looking on the web I found a solution for that, I just added the route field to the menu content element but that got me into another issue, when I switch languege the language switcher redirects me to home page because the URL it had to redirect to has the menu route translated into the current languege. For instance, if I'm on an article page , the english URL would be mysite/articles/articlename-id and if I switch language the URL has to be mysite/articulos/nombredelarticulo-id but the language switcher redirects to mysite/articles/nombredelarticulo-id. Is there any workaround that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best thing to do with this would be to use a dedicated SEF component such as [JoomSEF](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/site-management/sef/1063) (note other possibly better ones are available - especially if your willing to pay!). I'm suggesting this one as it states that it "Supports URL translations at multilingual sites using JoomFish/Falang." so should work seamlessly.

Comment: Sorry for accepting your answer so late, thakns for your help

Answer (score 1):

JoomSEF might not be the best solution in your case, depending on how your site is organized. JoomSEF writes urls according to category/content instead of the menu tree. Your url's will look like this: "home/category/subcategory/article-title", instead of: "home/menu-item/submenu-item". So whatever menu alias you put in your falang translation won't be used by JoomSEF. I have the same problem with falang, and I don't think there's a solution at all for the time being.

Comment: I tried using the default joomla translation system anly for the munus but didn't work. The site needs to have user friendly urls and I donnot think it is good to leave it that way, I mean with the urls with 2 languages, but I can't think of a solution